How would you utilize this crawl space?
Thinking about utilizing the crawl space for storage. A little hesitant to start anything because I'm unsure about the approach when dealing with unfinished space. Obviously, I don't want to attract pests so planning to place everything in plastic containers and above the ground (disregard the plastic container in the picture). Can I drill into the concrete wall and create some shelves? Will that, in any way, weaken the structure of the house? Or perhaps a 10x10 landing with some concrete blocks? Or perhaps pour some concrete?
There are several channels (french drain) underneath the vapor barrier that I wouldn't want to disturb.
I want to do it safely with minimal impairment to integrity of the house, while also preventing moisture and pests.
Thanks a lot


Most concrete walls can be drilled in for adding stuff with in reason.  A 3/8 or 1/2 inch(anchor) hole every few inches should not hurt.

This "crawlspace" is larger than most basement foundations. Yeesh!
